# How can I protect my lua script against having the global table dumped?

Tags: lua

How can I protect my lua script against [having the global table dumped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384718/how-to-dump-all-g-table-content)?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.lua.org/pil/15.4.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lua 5.2 or above, the `pairs` function will check the `__pairs` metamethod. If one exists, it will call that to generate the enumeration data for the `pairs` call. You can therefore prevent someone from iterating over the global table by giving that table a `__pairs` metamethod that either returns an "empty" iterator (`return function() return nil end, nil, nil`) or which just fails with `error`.

However, Lua's `next` function (which is *not* part of the `debug` library) doesn't care about the `__pairs` metamethod. It provides iteration over the entire table.

So you will also need to either remove `next` from what the script can access or wrap `next` with a function that, if the table has a `__pairs` metamethod, will return `nil` or `error` out.

Pre-Lua 5.2, you will have to write your own version of `pairs` (and `next`) that effectively does these things (that is, check for a `__pairs` metamethod and act appropriately.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Please note that I am using LUA 5.3

Comment: setmetatable(_G, {__pairs = function (t) return nil end})

i tried this but it apparently stopped all functions

Answer (score -1):

## 1. Executing a function with a global table that is a subset of the actual global table

You can use the [setfenv](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-setfenv) function for that ( more details [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/14.3.html) )

Example (Lua <5.2):

```lua
function someMaliciousFunction()
    -- do stuff
end

someMaliciousFunction = setfenv(someMaliciousFunction, {
    -- cherry-pick whatever this function should be able to do
    ["print"] = _G.print
})

-- the function will see the table above as its _G table
someMaliciousFunction()
```

Example (Lua >=5.2):

```lua
function someMaliciousFunction()
    -- do stuff
end

local temp = _ENV
_ENV = {
    -- cherry-pick whatever this function should be able to do
    ["print"] = _G.print
}

-- the function will see the table above as its global table
someMaliciousFunction()

_ENV = temp
```

## 2. Temporarly overwrite the global table

You can also overwrite the global. This will prevent anyone from iterating over all items using `pairs` or `ipairs` but will keep qualified access to all globals.
Example:

```lua
local temp = _G
_G = setmetatable({}, {__index = temp, __newindex = temp})

someMaliciousFunction()

_G = temp
```

Comment: This cant be used on Lua 5.3. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: @matif_dev the second solution works fine in Lua 5.3. The first works by simply setting the `_ENV`

Comment: @codeflush-dev 2 things:
- I tried the second one and run the code and it still prints the function
- Can you give me an example of the first one in Lua 5.3?

Comment: @codeflush-dev i do not want to prohibite acess to some functions, I don't want this function to be dumpable when dumping the _G table.